# Manipulate melting point of frozen water

Tags: water, melting-point

How to manipulate water in way that ice melting point isn't 0°C, but for example 4°C?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing so would be to significantly increase the pressure. As you can see from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_melting_point#/media/File:Phase_diagram_of_water.svg) phase diagram, at a pressure of 1 GPa, water ice will remain frozen at temperatures up to about 30°C.